# How to hover over one chart to display a vertical line and tooltip on all charts in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js, onmouseover

I'm using D3.js with ReactJS I want to hover over one chart and display a vertical line and tooltip on all the other charts.

I'm able to get vertical line in only one chart at a time.
The expected result is to display a vertical line and tooltip across all charts.

this what I tried:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    d3.select(anchorEl)
      .on("mouseout.tooltip", () => {
        d3.select(ref.current).attr("opacity", 0);
      })
      .on("mouseover.tooltip", () => {
        d3.select(ref.current).attr("opacity", 1);
      })
      .on("mousemove.tooltip", (e) => {
        d3.select(ref.current)
          .selectAll(".tooltipLinePoint")
          .attr("opacity", 1);
        followPoints(e);
      });
  }, [anchorEl, followPoints]);
```

This is the actual code result [multiline-chart-tooltip-acoss-all-charts](https://codesandbox.io/s/d3react-multiline-chart-version-6-separate-components-tooltip-forked-b2i5e?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Draw the line for the current hovered chart and then draw the line for the others charts and the key is to use d3.select() and d3.selectAll().

```
  d3.select(ref.current)
    .select(".tooltipLine")
    .attr("x1", x)
    .attr("x2", x)
    .attr("y1", -margin.top)
    .attr("y2", height);

  d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
    .select(".tooltipLine")
    .attr("x1", x)
    .attr("x2", x)
    .attr("y1", -margin.top)
    .attr("y2", height);

  drawLine(baseXPos);
  drawContent(baseXPos);
  drawBackground();

  drawLineForOthers(baseXPos);
  drawContentForOthers(baseXPos);
  drawBackgroundForOthers();
```